# Командная строка не видит sys.argv. Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, веб-сервер, cgi

Всем доброго дня. В процессе изучения книги марка Лутца "программируем на python 4-е издание" столкнулся со следующим кодом:

```
"""
Implement an HTTP web server in Python which knows how to serve HTML
pages and run server-side CGI scripts coded in Python;  this is not
a production-grade server (e.g., no HTTPS, slow script launch/run on
some platforms), but suffices for testing, especially on localhost;

Serves files and scripts from the current working dir and port 80 by 
default, unless these options are specified in command-line arguments;
Python CGI scripts must be stored in webdir\cgi-bin or webdir\htbin;
more than one of this server may be running on the same machine to serve
from different directories, as long as they listen on different ports;
"""

import os, sys
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler

webdir = '.'   # where your HTML files and cgi-bin script directory live
port   = 80    # http://servername/ if 80, else use http://servername:xxxx/

if len(sys.argv) > 1: webdir = sys.argv[1]             # command-line args
if len(sys.argv) > 2: port   = int(sys.argv[2])        # else default ., 80
print('webdir "%s", port %s' % (webdir, port))

os.chdir(webdir)                                       # run in HTML root dir
srvraddr = ('', port)                                  # my hostname, portnumber
srvrobj  = HTTPServer(srvraddr, CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
srvrobj.serve_forever()
```

Это самый простой локальный сервер, который работает без нареканий. Но когда я пытаюсь ввести адрес сервера в sys.argv или порт, командная строка упорно не видит вводимых данных. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если убрать блок if len и присвоить webdir напрямую sys.argv[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0ZTG.png), выдаёт ошибку

> list index out of range

Ума не приложу, в чем может быть дело. Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: чтобы не гадать, добавьте `print(sys.argv)` перед `if len(sys.argv) > 1` строкой

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте задать вместо

```
webserver.py PyMailCgi
```

команду

```
python webserver.py PyMailCgi
```

Comment: это неверно, попробуйте скрипт, содержащий `print(sys.argv)` и запустите его приведёнными методами, чтобы убедиться, что `sys.argv[1]` одинаковый в обоих случаях.